# Android HorizontalScrollView Snap and Center Focus

Tags: java, android

Fairly new to Android dev. I am trying to create a HorizontalScrollView that snaps and filters images based on the centered object selected in a list. In the picture below, notice how the letter in the center of the screen should perform a set of specific commands. For example, when I scroll to "C" a popup with the message "C" should pop up.

I have created the HorizontalScrollView and populated the view with buttons. I am trying to figure out how to make it snap and how to identify the letter in the center at any given moment.

[image]

I have taken a look at ViewPager, but I don't think it will be able to do what I have described because I would like to have a set of letters displayed at any moment. I understand I will probably have to create a custom class. Could you provide any guidance?